# iPhone - isKindOfClass generates a linker error

Tags: iphone, class, linker

I have a class defined like this :

```
@interface ServerCall : NSObject {
// vars
}

// properties

// functions (init)

@end
```

and

```
@interface ServerNotification : ServerCall {
    // just vars
}
@end
```

I have a call in another class :

```
if ([call isKindOfClass:[ServerNotification class]])
   // do things
```

When building I have this error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ServerNotification", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ServerCommunication.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ServerNotification", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ServerCommunication.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also have in build settings "Symbols hidden by default" = NO

What did I miss ?

Comment: Could you tell me if 'call' is intended to be a member of the class or inherited from the class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker doesn't find implementations for your `ServerNotification` class. Do you have the matching implementation file added to your target?

Comment: Dawned, no... I didn't thought that was necessary for empty classes. (this one is not empty but another one in the same configuration is, and generates the linker error too). Thank you for your answer.